# How to create whole solution from published files of an asp.net core 3.1 project?

Tags: asp.net-core, obfuscation, deobfuscation, dotpeek

I lost one week of development because of not committing my code. I work on a personal project and I lost my code I only have the published version of my asp.net core 3.1 project. and my code is not obfuscated.
I use DotPeek to open my main dll and I get controllers but there are no views in there ? I wonder to know, is there any way for me to create a solution like I had without creating views by my hand?
Is it possible to completely regenerate Visual Studio solution folder for this project from Published files?

Comment: I find out that there is another DLL file for views, so at least my main problem solved. but if there is a tool to make whole solution folder, I like to know.

Comment: unfortunately decompile project of views is not useful